# Send data periodically as a server to my client in arduino ESP8226

Tags: tcp, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm using NodeMCU board to communicate a laptop through WiFi. Basic communication is ok with a code like this:

```
void loop (){
WiFiClient client = server.available();

  if (client) {
    while (client.connected()){
       client.println(Data_mem[0]); 
       delay(2000);
    }
    client.stop();  // tarminates the connection with the client
   }
}
```

But when I want to send data a Timer Tick, it seems the client couldn't connect to me.

```
void setup(){
....
  //Initialize Ticker every 40ms
  Data_Rec.attach_ms(40, 40ms_Data );
}

void 40ms_Data (){
WiFiClient client = server.available();

  Serial.println("40ms_Data A");
  if (client) {
      Serial.println("40ms_Data B");
    if (client .connected()){
       Serial.println("40ms_Data C");    
       client.println(40ms_Data [0]); 
    }
    else{
       client.stop(); 
    }
   }
}
```

I arduino serial monitor, i see only this:
40ms_Data A \r\n
40ms_Data A \r\n
....
So, could anyone help me? maybe it a problem of `WiFiClient` deceleration in a non-forever loop (like example 1). But I have no idea to fix it.

According to M.R.'s idea, this is my complete new code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Ticker.h>

/* Put your SSID & Password */
const char* ssid = "NodeMCU";  // Enter SSID here
const char* password = "12345678";  //Enter Password here

/* Put IP Address details */
IPAddress local_ip(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);

WiFiServer server(80);                    
const int CLIENT_TIMEOUT = 2000;
Ticker Data_Rec;
bool Sending_40ms_Start_Flag = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(D0, OUTPUT);

  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(local_ip, gateway, subnet);
  delay(100);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
    Data_Rec.attach_ms(500, flag_enable);//500ms is for test
}

void flag_enable(){
    //Read FPGA Data from SPI
    //...
    Sending_40ms_Start_Flag = true;
}


void loop(){
    WiFiClient client = server.available();
    if (client) {
        while(client.connected()){
        Serial.println("40ms_Data B");
            if (Sending_40ms_Start_Flag){          
              client.println("Server listening.\r"); 
              Sending_40ms_Start_Flag = false;                            
            }
            delay(1);//without this delay, ESP would be reset(because it cannot handle background processes)
         }
//         else{
//           client.stop();
//         }
      }
}
```

This code worked. But the server RST the TCP connection after sending one,two or tree "Server listening." as Wireshark shows: [Wireshark Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGa5f.jpg)

What is probable cause of TCP Reset from ESP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is to adding this to setup function:
WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
Full explanation: [Here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/1384)
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Besides that some syntax errors in your code:
A good solution is to create a static pointer object from `client` and pass it as an argument to `ms40_Data` function:

```
void ms40_Data(WiFiClient *client)
{
    Serial.println("40ms_Data A");
    if (*client)
    {
        Serial.println("40ms_Data B");
        if (client->connected())
        {
            Serial.println("40ms_Data C");
            //client.println(40ms_Data [0]);
        }
        else
        {
            client->stop();
        }
    }
}

void setup()
{
    ...
    // create a static object from WiFiClient
    static WiFiClient client = server.available();
    //Initialize Ticker every 40ms
    Data_Rec.attach_ms(40, ms40_Data, &client);
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Another solution is, you can set a flag inside your ticker and then call your `ms40_Data` function:

```
bool start_40ms_Data = false;

void ms40_Data()
{
    static WiFiClient client = server.available();

    Serial.println("40ms_Data A");
    if (client)
    {
        Serial.println("40ms_Data B");
        if (client.connected())
        {
            Serial.println("40ms_Data C");
            //client.println(40ms_Data [0]);
        }
        else
        {
            client.stop();
        }
    }
}

void flag_enable()
{
    start_40ms_Data = true;
}

void setup()
{
    ...
    //Initialize Ticker every 40ms
    Data_Rec.attach_ms(40, flag_enable);
}

void loop()
{
    if (start_40ms_Data)
    {
        ms40_Data();
        start_40ms_Data = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the idea of static object don't worked. Data Send truly from client. But In ESP, there is no connected client seen!
 I get the idea of flag to make a new code as below. But some problems remained.

Comment: qtd from M. R:
The problem here is you are trying to create WiFiClient client each time inside your loop. You need to create client globally.

Comment: If i cut my WiFiClient declaration line and set it under Sending_40ms_Start_Flag declaration, ESP don't come in the if (client) { while(client.connected()){...}} loop at all. In the present code, i'm in the infinite loop:while(client.connected()){...}. Why we need global declaration?